# My Ground sprite disappearing for a couple seconds than coming back and player falling and not returning back

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I found this may have to do with the `setScale`, I tried it with a few different sizes and the ground don't disappear after few seconds when on `3.0-4.0,` but those scale sizes are way too big for the game. I need to use `setScale(1.0)`. I've tested it many times with different sizes,

however I `setScale(1.0)` is the size I need for the ground sprite.

Here is the code:

```
 func createGround() {
 let groundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ground")
    groundTexture.filteringMode = .nearest


for _ in stride(from: 0, to: 2 + self.frame.size.width / groundTexture.size().width, by: 1) { //i

        let ground = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundTexture)
        ground.zPosition = -10 
    ground.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5,y:0.5)

        ground.position = CGPoint(x: 0 - self.size.width / 2 + ground.size.width / 2, y: 0 - self.size.height / 2 + ground.size.height / 2)

        ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width * 2.0, height: groundTexture.size().height / 1.0)) 
       ground.setScale(1.0) //1.0 is the number I need however it disappears after a few seconds and the character falls and doesn't come back.

        ground.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        ground.physicsBody?.allowsRotation  = false
        ground.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        ground.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
        ground.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = groundCategory
        ground.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory | enemy1Category | enemy2Category | enemy3Category | enemy4Category | obstacleCategory | coinCatergory
   // ground.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask =  playerCategory | enemy1Category | enemy2Category | enemy3Category | enemy4Category | obstacleCategory | coinCatergory
  ground.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0 //tried with 0 and with catergories
    ground.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.0
        //ground.zPosition = 4.0 //see if zPosition makes the robot stay
    //    self.addChild(ground)

   let moveLeft = SKAction.moveBy(x: -groundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 7)
   let moveReset = SKAction.moveBy(x: groundTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0)
   let moveLoop = SKAction.sequence([moveLeft, moveReset])
   let moveForever = SKAction.repeatForever(moveLoop)
      ground.run(moveForever)
    self.addChild(ground)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question. It seems a bit ambiguous. Your player is falling and disappeared because your ground collisionbitmask is set to 0. your player collisionbitmask should be set to groundCategory, and grounds collisionbitmask should be playerCategory or  others whichever stands on the ground. otherwise anything would fall through the ground.

Comment: I tried with ground.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask =  playerCategory | enemy1Category | enemy2Category | enemy3Category | enemy4Category | obstacleCategory | coinCatergory  and the player still falls through. and I declared its collisionbitmask to groundcategory.

Comment: only player is falling? what about other sprites like enemy1, enemy2 or obstacle?